# How to use Xcode built-in unit testing framework to test C functions?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode, unit-testing

I'm trying to unit test C functions with the SenTestingKit framework. I declares functions in a header file and defines implementations in a corresponding C file. And I imports the header file in the unit test class. But when I build the test cases, the build result says the functions 'symbol(s) not found'. 
Is there anything I should do to make it work? 
Is it the right way to unit test C functions?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the implementation file to the Unit Test target so it gets compiled in. Importing the header is not enough.